# How to just build poms that contain changed files in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have a super pom that contains many sub module poms.  The super pom build takes around 5 min.  Currently, I just rebuild the top level every time I want to test my changes even though the changes maybe all within one or just a few of the sub modules and seldom ever span more than 20% of all the poms.  So doing the full build is time consuming and inefficient.

Is there a way (like a Maven plugin or built in already) for Maven to detect in which poms the changes are and rebuild only those poms, saving me a lot of time?  I was thinking that could be accomplished by comparing the time stamps of all the source files that are getting built with those of the jars they go into and detect the changes defined as those source files that have the time stamp greater than their jar.  Then just build those poms following the build sequence based on the dependencies.

Comment: `mvn -pl ...` in combination with `mvn -amd -pl project` from your root project.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like more of a task for a CI system like Jenkins.  Have separate jobs in Jenkins for each sub-project and only build them when the code for them changes.  They each publish their dependencies to a SNAPSHOT repository and then you can build dependencies, etc.

Comment: no, this should be enabled in a simple local development env.  not on the build server

Comment: You have to know what changed then and manually build each project - i.e. there's not a way to do this (that I know of).

Comment: i was hoping Maven (or a plugin) would be smart enough to detect it like i described in the OP

Comment: Maven doesn't even know how to do this for a single build.  i.e. if you run mvn install, then run mvn install again it will go through all the same steps (even for a single project).  I think many would argue that this is by design.

Comment: well maybe it should cause it's not that hard to do.  it's just tedious

Comment: It's not that hard for your particular use case where you only have dependencies on source code in your local build tree or dependencies - what if I had dependencies on web resources or the vast myriad of other possibilities?  I'm not saying you're wrong (even "Make" had this functionality way back when), I just think it's by design.